# button disappears after screen rotation

Tags: java, android, button, screen-rotation

I have a simple app that has a Button and a TextView, when I try screen rotation, the TextView stays same while the Button disappears as below.

[image]

The Button comes back when I rotate the screen again.

[image]

I couldn't find a solution, is this a possible bug?

1- Why does this happening, I guess it's about onCreate() state, but why does TextView stays while the Button disappears?

2- How to solve this issue

3- I'm using Bundle to save the number, is it related to this problem?

I'm using the latest version of Android Studio. Here is my code

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.kalicidegiskenler;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView t1;
    Button b1;
    int say;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        t1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text1);
        b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

        if (savedInstanceState != null){

            say = savedInstanceState.getInt("sayac");
            t1.setText(String.valueOf(say));
        }
        else {
            say = 0;
        }
        
        b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                say ++;
                t1.setText(String.valueOf(say));
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(@NonNull Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

        outState.putInt("sayac", say);
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.12" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="159dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="159dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="513dp"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: It's because `app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf` is used: the button is placed 513dp from the bottom of the screen. In lanscape, that's somewhere above the toolbar and so you cannot see it.

Comment: @Michiel That's actually makes sense but Button also has constraint from top, shouldn't it put the Button between those constraints from top and bottom? Why does Bottom constraint "overwrites" top constraint?

Comment: The `TextView` indeed has all 4 constraints set, the `Button` does not: it only has a bottom and start constraint. One thing that is overwritten, is the left margin by the start margin. The question is, where would you place the button? If you want to place it under the tetxtview, you also could add: `app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/text1"` and change  `android:layout_marginBottom` in a smaller value.

Comment: @Michiel could you write your comment as the answer, I don't want to delete the question so future visitors could see it.

Comment: don't think this has anything to do with android studio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because the button is drawn out of screen; somewhere above the toolbar.

With `app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf` used in combination with a padding of 513dp, the button falls out of the screen width (or landscape height) of 320 dp.

If you align it directly under the text, it will be always visible:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"

        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.12" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/text1"        
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"

        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:text="Button" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Pro-tip: Google advises to use multiples of 8dp for paddings, margins and sizes. This scales well on different screen sizes and it is aesthetically pleasing if views fall in a grid.